# How to change font and size of buttons and frame in tkinter using python?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

This is the code that i used to generate a simple text box and a button in tkinter.

What should be the parameters to have a better look of the frame and buttons?

```
 root = Tk.Tk()

 def submit():
    query = entry.get()
    retrieve(query)
    entry = Tk.Entry(root)
    entry.pack()
    button = Tk.Button(root, text='submit', command=submit)
    button.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*UPDATE*: The New Mexico Tech tkinter website has been archived on GitHub.

First the best reference for Tkinter is [this New Mexico Tech website](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/index.html). In the toc you will find a [section on fonts](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/fonts.html), and in the [section on Button widgets](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/button.html) you'll find the option `font`.

you must have a Tkinter object to create a font

#### Python-2

[Support for Python-2 has officially ended as of Jan 1, 2020](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/)

```
from Tkinter import *  # Note: UPPER case "T" in Tkinter
import tkFont
root = Tk()
```

#### Python-3

[Python-3 Tk wrappers differ from Python-2](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/tkinter.html)

```
from tkinter import *  # Note: lower case "t" in tkinter
from tkinter import font as tkFont  # for convenience
root = Tk()
```

create a font like the example from New Mexico Tech website

```
helv36 = tkFont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=36, weight='bold')
# you don't have to use Helvetica or bold, this is just an example
```

*(**Note**: recall for Python-3 `font` was imported as `tkFont` for convenience)*

now you can set the font for `button` created from `Button` in the original post

```
button['font'] = helv36
```

The size of the button will depend on your geometry manager, EG: `grid` or `pack`. Only the `grid` method is covered in the [layouts section](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/layout-mgt.html) by New Mexico Tech site, but [effbot.org](http://effbot.org/) is also a great reference and he covers [`pack`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm) pretty well.

```
try:  # Python-2
    from Tkinter import *
    import tkFont
except ImportError:  # Python-3
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import font as tkFont
# using grid
# +------+-------------+
# | btn1 |    btn2     |
# +------+------+------+
# | btn3 | btn3 | btn4 |
# +-------------+------+
root = Tk()
# tkFont.BOLD == 'bold'
helv36 = tkFont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=36, weight=tkFont.BOLD)
btn1 = Button(text='btn1', font=helv36)
btn2 = Button(text='btn2', font=helv36)
btn3 = Button(text='btn3', font=helv36)
btn4 = Button(text='btn4', font=helv36)
btn5 = Button(text='btn5', font=helv36)
root.rowconfigure((0,1), weight=1)  # make buttons stretch when
root.columnconfigure((0,2), weight=1)  # when window is resized
btn1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=1, sticky='EWNS')
btn2.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky='EWNS')
btn3.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=1, sticky='EWNS')
btn4.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=1, sticky='EWNS')
btn5.grid(row=1, column=2, columnspan=1, sticky='EWNS')
```

[image: Tkinter Button fonts]

Also try `ttk`.

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkFont'  in line 1 :(

Comment: Sorry @AbdullahSaid My response written nearly 6 years ago was for Python-2.7, so I've updated it for Python-. When using Python-3 you must import [`tkinter.font`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/tkinter.font.html) instead of `tkfont`.

Comment: thanks for the reply @MarkMikofski, sorry I didn't realize this posted 6 years ago haha. I was really confused yesterday but yeah I figure it out already. however, some of the stylings are different between Windows and OSX, especially about buttons inside the grid. I've tried it on both operating machines (Windows and OSX) and result in a huge difference between each other. it's way harder to configure in OSX

Answer (score 8):

[tkdocs tutorial](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/fonts.html) recommends using named fonts and styles if you want to tweak the appearences:

```
import random
try:
    import tkinter as Tk
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk
    import tkinter.font as font
except ImportError: # Python 2
    import Tkinter as Tk
    import ttk
    import tkFont as font

def change_font_family(query, named_font):
    named_font.configure(family=random.choice(font.families()))

root = parent = Tk.Tk()
root.title("Change font demo")

# standard named font (everything that uses it will change)
font.nametofont('TkDefaultFont').configure(size=5) # tiny

# you can use your own font
MyFont = font.Font(weight='bold')

query = Tk.StringVar()
ttk.Entry(parent, textvariable=query, font=MyFont).grid() # set font directly
ttk.Button(parent, text='Change Font Family',  style='TButton', # or use style
           command=lambda: change_font_family(query, MyFont)).grid()
query.set("The quick brown fox...")

# change font that widgets with 'TButton' style use
root.after(3000, lambda: ttk.Style().configure('TButton', font=MyFont))
# change font size for everything that uses MyFont
root.after(5000, lambda: MyFont.configure(size=48)) # in 5 seconds
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This worked but how can i change the frame size or re-position the button in the frame?Is there any drag and drop interface that works properly over python with Tkinter?

Comment: @AbhijathBenhur: It is a job [for a layout manager](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html). See example in [@Mark Mikofski's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20588878/4279). I've never used a GUI builder for tkinter interfaces. You could [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about it as a separate question.

Comment: Use [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) with the Python binding [PyQt4](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download). It includes a GUI builder called [Qt Designer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-manual.html). There are also help and locale builders (Qt Assistance an Qt Linguist). Note Qt Creator is an IDE for C/C++ and Java. Qt is a mainstream, modern UI framework that abstracts the GUI, help and localization from the backend by using a markup language, called [QML](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/gettingstartedqml.html), which Qt Designer generates automatically.

Comment: `ttk` which uses `style` is definitely the way to go if sticking with Tkinter. `ttk` will look much nicer than the Tkinter widgets, because it's designed to match the OS style. EG: progress bar looks like a Windows 7 progress bar on Windows 7, an XP progress bar on Windows XP and a Gnome progress bar on a Linux with a Gnome desktop, etc. IMHO do not use [`tix`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tix.html); it hasn't been updated in 5 years.

Answer (score 1):

use the command `font = font.Font(size = 20)` to change the looking of text in button

```
import tkinter.font as fnt
import tkinter as tk
r=tk.Tk()
tk.Button(r,text = "Test", font = fnt.Font(size = 20))
r.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this one as well.  It took lots of research.

But I found one way, maybe the easiest way, maybe the only way, probably the most direct way:

Use styling.

In your window class:

```
     style = ttk.Style(self)
     style.configure('TButton', font = ('Helvetica', 20)
```

That should do it.