# I've tried to change my font size and it still has no affect. How do I actually change the font size?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to change the font size of my buttons in Tkinter so it's not so small. Does anyone have any idea on what I can do that might have the result that I'm looking for? Why is there so much text required for me to ask a question when I can ask it plainly and simply with less text?!

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkFont import *


class App:
    def __init__(self):
        guiWindow = Tkinter.Tk()
        guiWindow.wm_title("FooBar")

        # Creates a custom font
        customFont = Font(size=18)

        # code to add widgets will go here
        buttonFrame = Frame()

        # colors the "ChangeLicense" button
        color = '#005DA6'

        # tells licenseChange what to do
        def openLicenseChange():
            print('Change License')

    #button properties
        licenseChange = Button(guiWindow,
                               command=openLicenseChange,
                               bd=20, bg=color, font=customFont,
                               text="Change License")

        buttonFrame.pack(side="top", fill="x")

        guiWindow.mainloop()
app=App()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change font and size of buttons and frame in tkinter using python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20588417/how-to-change-font-and-size-of-buttons-and-frame-in-tkinter-using-python)

Comment: I don't understand the question. Your code does create a button with a large font. What problem are you having? When I ran your code (and added `licenseChange.pack()`, a large 18pt button appeared.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `Font`, but you can denote it also using a string:

```
customFont = '{arial} 18'
```

For default font uer

```
customFont = '{} 18'
```

Comment: I just tried that and is producing the same result as if the font were default size. To make sure the font wasn't already 18 I changed it to 32 and still the same result. Any other ideas?

Comment: I haven't tried your code, but I see you haven't packed the licenseChange button. You may try it...

Comment: Hey sorry, i just got back to work and able to look at this. I noticed that in my troubleshooting of the font thing that I must have accidentally removed that as well. My trouble is still there - does this solution work with other code snippets or on your machine with my code? I might just be a bad coder (probably the case since this is only my second or third attempt at programming) Thanks again for the assistance you've offered to far.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a `tk.button` object, use the font option, and specify the font style as a string like so:
`"Arial 10 Bold"`

I used your code as an example and made the font Arial, size 18, bolded.

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkFont import *


class App:
    def __init__(self):
        guiWindow = Tkinter.Tk()
        guiWindow.wm_title("FooBar")

        # Creates a custom font
        customFont = "Arial 18 Bold"

        # code to add widgets will go here
        buttonFrame = Frame()

        # colors the "ChangeLicense" button
        color = '#005DA6'

        # tells licenseChange what to do
        def openLicenseChange():
            print('Change License')

    #button properties
        licenseChange = Button(guiWindow,
                               command=openLicenseChange,
                               bd=20, bg=color, font=customFont,
                               text="Change License")

        buttonFrame.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        licenseChange.pack()
        guiWindow.mainloop()
app=App()
```

If that doesnt work, instead of `"Arial 18 Bold"`, try quoting each word in the string like so `"'Arial' '18' 'Bold'"` in your `customFont` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new font and then just applying it to your widgets using `my_widget['font']=my_font`, example out of your code:

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkFont import *


class App:

    def __init__(self):
        guiWindow = Tkinter.Tk()
        guiWindow.wm_title("FooBar")

        # Creates a custom font
        customFont = Font(size=18)

        # code to add widgets will go here
        buttonFrame = Frame()

        # colors the "ChangeLicense" button
        color = '#005DA6'

        # tells licenseChange what to do
        def openLicenseChange():
            print('Change License')

        # button properties
        helv36 = Font(family='Helvetica', size=36, weight='bold')
        licenseChange = Button(guiWindow,
                               command=openLicenseChange,
                               bd=20, bg=color, font=customFont,
                               text="Change License")
        licenseChange['font'] = helv36
        buttonFrame.pack(side="top", fill="x")

        guiWindow.mainloop()

app = App()
```

You can read more about tkFont.Font [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_fonts.htm)

Comment: I tried this by modifying what you gave me to my code and it didn't work. Then I tried literally copy and pasting which still doesn't work. My font still comes up as the default font. I appreciate your input, any other ideas?

Comment: @AveryLipsit Could you elaborate a little bit more? Could you make a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code so I'll be able to diagnose what's going on

Comment: Sure thing! I didn't even realize that was a thing thanks! One moment...

Comment: I have to head home from work now... I'll update in a bit... sorry :(